# Solving a structured partitioned linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the following partitioned linear system, where each letter represents a **block**

$\begin{pmatrix}-H & A^T & I_n \\ A & 0_1 & 0_2 \\ z_D & 0_2^T & x_D\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} dx \\ dy  \\ dz \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r_d \\ r_p  \\ r_p \end{pmatrix}$

Where:

- H is $n$ x $n$, non-invertible, but dense and structured $H=B-CC^T$
- A is $c$ x $n$, and can be sparse
- I is square $n$ x $n$ identity
- $0_1$ is square $c$ x $c$, $0_2$ is $c$ x $n$
- $z_D$ is diag(z), and $x_D$ diag(x) where both $z$ and $x$ are column vectors
- Middle and RHS terms are partitioned column vectors

The entire matrix on LHS is full-rank and all numbers are real.

I tried solving the inverse symbolically, but had $H^{-1}$ appear. Likewise, when using Mathematica to show element-wise solution I couldn't see a pattern.

Looking into iterative solutions, the closest found is Conjugate Residual Method ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_residual_method)), but unless $z_D=I_n$ it is not Hermitian, which is required for that method.

The order of n is about 100,000; smaller sizes the solution can just be found by normal programs - but after a certain size it becomes impractical.

Comment: Is $z_D$ or $x_D$ nonsingular? If $x_D$ is invertible, you can eliminate $dz$ from the system and if nothing else, at least the resulting matrix will be symmetric. Then you can use any symmetric iterative solver such as [MINRES](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/minres/) (also implemented in the sparse toolbox in MATLAB).